# Сортировка массива

Tags: php, массивы, сортировка

Дали тестовое задание, php владею не плохо, но вот суть задания не понял. Может кто поможет и покажет.

ЗАДАНИЕ - написать функцию сортировки массива $TH, такую чтоб можно было на вход подать имя ключа и он по его значению отсортировал массив $TH

```
<?php

$m = array('a'=>'Honda','b'=>'Hummer','c'=>'BMW','d'=>'Toyota'); 
$s = array('a'=>'AH','b'=>'TU-144','c'=>'Boing','d'=>'СУ'); 
$t = array('a'=>'Тигр','b'=>'Пантера','c'=>'Т-34','d'=>'Волга'); 
$k = array('a'=>'Кузнецов','b'=>'Ямато','c'=>'Ясень','d'=>'Петропавловск'); 

$TH = array($m, $s, $t, $k); 

//Т.Е. Было:

Array
(
    [0] => Array
       (
           [a] => Honda
           [b] => Hummer
           [c] => BMW 
           [d] => Toyota
       )

   [1] => Array
       (
           [a] => AH
           [b] => TU-144
           [c] => Boing
           [d] => СУ
       )

   [2] => Array
       (
           [a] => Тигр
           [b] => Пантера
           [c] => Т-34
           [d] => Волга
       )

   [3] => Array
       (
           [a] => Кузнецов
           [b] => Ямато
           [c] => Ясень
           [d] => Петропавловск
       )

)


//Стало:

Array
(
   [1] => Array
       (
           [a] => AH
           [b] => TU-144
           [c] => Boing
           [d] => СУ
       )

   [0] => Array
       (
           [a] => Honda
           [b] => Hummer
           [c] => BMW
           [d] => Toyota
       )

   [3] => Array
       (
           [a] => Кузнецов
           [b] => Ямато
           [c] => Ясень
           [d] => Петропавловск
       )

   [2] => Array
       (
           [a] => Тигр
           [b] => Пантера
           [c] => Т-34
           [d] => Волга
       )

)
```

Comment: где выдали задание? и почему там не могут объяснить его?

Comment: Обычное тестовое задание, при приеме на работу. К сожалению нету оперативной обратной связи

Comment: В общем дают на вход `"a"`, значит надо отсортировать массивы по алфавиту значений в ячейках `a`.......если дают `"c"`, то по алфавиту основанном в ячейках `c` и т.д. .......... используй [usort](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.usort.php) и [strcmp](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.strcmp.php)

Comment: спасибо понял..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот пример реализации вашего вопроса с помощью метода `usort`:

```
<?php

    $m = array('a'=>'Honda','b'=>'Hummer','c'=>'BMW','d'=>'Toyota'); 
    $s = array('a'=>'AH','b'=>'TU-144','c'=>'Boing','d'=>'СУ'); 
    $t = array('a'=>'Тигр','b'=>'Пантера','c'=>'Т-34','d'=>'Волга'); 
    $k = array('a'=>'Кузнецов','b'=>'Ямато','c'=>'Ясень','d'=>'Петропавловск'); 

    $TH = array($m, $s, $t, $k);

    echo '<pre>';
    print_r($TH);



    function sort_arr($arr, $key){

        uasort($arr, function ($a, $b) use ($key) {

            if ($a[$key] == $b[$key]) return 0;
            return ($a[$key] < $b[$key]) ? -1 : 1;

        });
        echo '<pre>';
        print_r($arr);

    }

    sort_arr($TH, 'a');

    sort_arr($TH, 'c');

?>
```

Подробно об этой строке `uasort($arr, function ($a, $b) use ($key)`:

внутри `callback` функции не видны внешние переменные, их можно задать так `use ($param1, $param2,...)` что бы они были видны внутри функции .

И вот 2 вывода `print_r` сортированные первый параметром `a`, и второй параметром `c`.

Сортировка `a`:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [a] => AH
            [b] => TU-144
            [c] => Boing
            [d] => СУ
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [a] => Honda
            [b] => Hummer
            [c] => BMW
            [d] => Toyota
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [a] => Кузнецов
            [b] => Ямато
            [c] => Ясень
            [d] => Петропавловск
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [a] => Тигр
            [b] => Пантера
            [c] => Т-34
            [d] => Волга
        )

)
```

Сортировка `c`:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [a] => Honda
            [b] => Hummer
            [c] => BMW
            [d] => Toyota
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [a] => AH
            [b] => TU-144
            [c] => Boing
            [d] => СУ
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [a] => Тигр
            [b] => Пантера
            [c] => Т-34
            [d] => Волга
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [a] => Кузнецов
            [b] => Ямато
            [c] => Ясень
            [d] => Петропавловск
        )

)
```

Comment: Все верно спасибо, только вы не обратили внимание на ключи, если справить usort на uasort то все в точности как надо.

Comment: @АбдуллаевМухаммед спасибо за примечание.

Comment: @RazmikGalstyan Исправьте `usort` и во вводной фразе, пожалуйста. И будет удобно ссылку на http://php.net/manual/ru/function.uasort.php добавить....

Comment: ну вот зачем....зачем......

Comment: @АлексейШиманский как то не понял?